# How can I issue a command to a linux system via c#?

Tags: c#, linux, command-line, ssh

Using C#, I need to send a `date` command to set the time on a linux system.

How can I connect to this system and send this command in code?

What library can I use to do this?

Update: I'm really looking for a free solution, thank you...

Comment: what is listening on the linux system ?

Comment: Do you want to do this locally, or remotely send the command?

Comment: @Felice Pollano - I don't understand your question. I'm just connecting as root on the system.

Comment: @ kyndigs - the linux system is a remote computer

Comment: @Julien I suppsed you where on an external system running windows and you need to call a command remotely on linux

Comment: @Felice Pollano - Yes, that is exaclty the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using the SharpSSH library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/

Answer (score 1):

You could use ChilkatDotNet components to ssh/telnet to your linux box, and run the command - otherwise you would need a client app to sit and listen.

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_DotNet.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need some SSH component for .NET to access the remote system. There are plenty on the market, from free (and outdated) SharpSSH to our [SSHBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssh.php).

Comment: @Eugene: Please back your statement about SharpSSH being outdated with a link or some other sort of info. A short [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sharpssh%20outdated) didn't turn anything up...

Comment: @Daniel http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx , "SharpSSH is now hosted on sourceforge. Latest SharpSSH version is 1.1.1.13 (Jun-24-2007)" , http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/files/SharpSSH/1.1.1.13/

Comment: @Eugene: Has the SSH protocol changed since 2007?

Comment: @Daniel the protocol, implementations ... While you might find that SharpSSH works with some set of servers, it will either fail or misbehave on newer versions of SSH servers. Ensuring compatibility with various SSH servers is aiming a running target and without constant updates SSH/SFTP client becomes outdated quite fast.

Comment: @Eugene: While I don't really have base for the following, I am still certain, it is correct: According to wikipedia, the latest version of SSH is SSH Generation 3, Version 2, in short: SSH-2. This has been released in 2006. If SharpSSH supported it back then, it supports it now. That's what protocol definitions are for. As long, as you don't have specifics on why SharpSSH is outdated, I dismiss your statement as discrediting the competitor. This in turn disqualifies you and your product... Sure, this is just my POV and you can ignore it, but it felt like this the first time (cont.)

Comment: @Daniel whatever your perception is, it doesn't update SharpSSH.

Comment: @Eugene : I'm not going to pay over $200 just to send a single command. Besides, SharpSSH does the job very well :-)

Comment: @Julien no problems, until you face the incompatibility or something gets magically broken. Support is what you *don't* get with open-source.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Mono(http://mono-project.com/Writing_a_WebService).
You can simply implement web service same way on Windows.

Comment: I can't make modifications to the linux system, barely just connect to it